# how i can disable button function after some clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 buttons, each button add an image element to page ... 
I want to my client be able to add only 14 element by click on the each button that like ... 
It means that if client clicked five times on button 1, five times on button 2, two times on button 3 and two times on button 4 : all buttons fell into disable ...
thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Fast Food</title>
    <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(80px);transform:translateZ(80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(80px);transform:translateZ(80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bottom{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(50px);transform:translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bottom{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(50px);transform:translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-br{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-br{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(-80px);transform:translateZ(-80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(-80px);transform:translateZ(-80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-right{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px);transform:translateX(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-right{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px);transform:translateX(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-tl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-tl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-top{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);transform:translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-top{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);transform:translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-tr{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-tr{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}
    .fade-in{-webkit-animation:fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both;animation:fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both}
    .main{
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        background-image: #000;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .pduct{

    }
    .btnS{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        font-family: 'El Messiri';
        font-weight:100;
        color:cornsilk;
    }
    #footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;" >
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll; height:650px; max-height: 650px; border-radius:8px; background-image: linear-gradient(#fff , rgb(236, 154, 154) , rgba(236, 0, 0, 0.993)); margin-top: 25px;;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
<center><img src="http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174142/head.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin: 10px;"></center>

<center><div id="mini" class="main"></div></center>

<center><img src="http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174150/footer.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top: 10px; "></center>

</div>
<div class="container" id="footer">
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="burger()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(172, 107, 83);" id="test">برگر</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="Lettuce()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(0, 129, 0);">کاهو</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="tomato()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(221, 8, 8);">گوجه</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="cheese()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(182, 103, 0);">پنیر</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function burger(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174184/burg.png');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '35px');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
}
</script>
<script>
function Lettuce(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174126/kahoo.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '20px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
}
</script>
<script>
 function tomato(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174118/tomato.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '25px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
}
</script>
<script>
function cheese(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174168/cheese.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '10px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if your client press one button 14 time so all buttons will be disable? am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help a bit.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var count = 0;
   buttonID.onclick = function(){
       if (count >= 14)
       {
           button1ID.disabled = true;
           button2ID.disabled = true;
           button3ID.disabled = true;
           button4ID.disabled = true;
       }
       else
           count++;
   };
}
```

you can use it either this way or by putting code from if condition in JS function that you call on each button click sometjhing like below function  `disableAllButtons`

```
function disableAllButtons(){
    //var count= 0; // This needs to be defined out of function. Putting it here just for reference
    if (count >= 14) {
           button1ID.disabled = true;
           button2ID.disabled = true;
           button3ID.disabled = true;
           button4ID.disabled = true;
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function cheese(){
    var burger = document.createElement('img');
    burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174168/cheese.png');
    burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
    burger.setAttribute('height' , '10px');
    burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
    document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);

     count();
 }

function count(){

 if(document.getElementById("mini").childElementCount == 14)
    {
        button1ID.disabled = true;
        button2ID.disabled = true;
        button3ID.disabled = true;
        button4ID.disabled = true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply used your code to make it easy. You need to create a global variable and then increment it on every button click and when condition matches just disable the buttons

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Fast Food</title>
    <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(80px);transform:translateZ(80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bck{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(80px);transform:translateZ(80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-bottom{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(50px);transform:translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-bottom{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(50px);transform:translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-br{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-br{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(-80px);transform:translateZ(-80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(-80px);transform:translateZ(-80px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-left{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-right{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px);transform:translateX(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-right{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px);transform:translateX(50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-tl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-tl{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-top{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);transform:translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-top{0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);transform:translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-tr{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in-tr{0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);transform:translateX(50px) translateY(-50px);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);transform:translateX(0) translateY(0);opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}
    .fade-in{-webkit-animation:fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both;animation:fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both}
    .main{
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        background-image: #000;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .pduct{

    }
    .btnS{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        font-family: 'El Messiri';
        font-weight:100;
        color:cornsilk;
    }
    #footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;" >
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll; height:650px; max-height: 650px; border-radius:8px; background-image: linear-gradient(#fff , rgb(236, 154, 154) , rgba(236, 0, 0, 0.993)); margin-top: 25px;;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
<center><img src="http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174142/head.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin: 10px;"></center>

<center><div id="mini" class="main"></div></center>

<center><img src="http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174150/footer.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top: 10px; "></center>

</div>
<div class="container" id="footer">
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="burger()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(172, 107, 83);" id="test">1</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="Lettuce()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(0, 129, 0);">2</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="tomato()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(221, 8, 8);">3</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="cheese()" class="btnS" style="background-color: rgb(182, 103, 0);">4
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var count = 0
var disable = document.getElementsByClassName('btnS');
function burger(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174184/burg.png');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
burger.setAttribute('alt' , 'burger');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '35px');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
count +=1
if(count == 14 ){
disable[0].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[1].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[2].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[3].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
}
}
function Lettuce(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174126/kahoo.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('alt' , 'kahoo');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '20px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
count +=1
if(count == 14 ){
disable[0].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[1].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[2].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[3].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
}
}

 function tomato(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174118/tomato.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('alt' , 'tomato');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '25px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
count +=1
if(count == 14 ){
disable[0].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[1].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[2].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[3].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
}
}

function cheese(){
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174168/cheese.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '10px');
burger.setAttribute('alt' , 'cheese');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);
count +=1
if(count == 14 ){
disable[0].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[1].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[2].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
disable[3].setAttribute('disabled' ,true);
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey 100% tested Answer -hope this will help u- do changes after body-

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<body style="background-color: black;" >
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll; height:650px; max-height: 650px; border-radius:8px; background-image: linear-gradient(#fff , rgb(236, 154, 154) , rgba(236, 0, 0, 0.993)); margin-top: 25px;;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
<center><img src="http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174142/head.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin: 10px;"></center>

<center><div id="mini" class="main"></div></center>

<center><img src="http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174150/footer.png" style="width: 70%; height:auto; margin:auto; margin-top: 10px; "></center>

</div>
<div class="container" id="footer">
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="burger();cnt();" class="btnS" id="myBtn3" style="background-color: rgb(172, 107, 83);" id="test">برگر</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="Lettuce();cnt();" class="btnS" id="myBtn2" style="background-color: rgb(0, 129, 0);">کاهو</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="tomato();cnt();" class="btnS" id="myBtn1" style="background-color: rgb(221, 8, 8);">گوجه</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
<button onclick="cheese();cnt();" class="btnS" id="myBtn" style="background-color: rgb(182, 103, 0);">پنیر</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    var clicks=0;
    count=0;
function burger(){
      clicks += 1;

var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174184/burg.png');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '35px');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);

}

function Lettuce(){
      clicks += 1;
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s6.picofile.com/file/8378174126/kahoo.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '20px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);

}

 function tomato(){
      clicks += 1;
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174118/tomato.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '25px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);

}


function cheese(){
    clicks += 1;
var burger = document.createElement('img');
burger.setAttribute('src' , 'http://s7.picofile.com/file/8378174168/cheese.png');
burger.setAttribute('width' , '80%');
burger.setAttribute('height' , '10px');
burger.setAttribute('class' , 'fade-in');
document.getElementById('mini').appendChild(burger);

}

function cnt()
{

var x=clicks;
if(x==14)
{
    myFunction();

}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("myBtn1").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("myBtn3").disabled = true;
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```